# Repeat array elements k times in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Sample data of DF with an array column:

```
+--------------------+
|         COL1       |
+--------------------+
|[A, B, C]           |
+--------------------+
```

I tried with [array_repeat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_repeat) but my datatype is already of ArrayType

```
df.select(array_repeat(df.COL1, 2).alias('C')).collect()
```

Output:

```
+----------------------+
|         C            |
+----------------------+
|[[A, B, C],[A, B, C]] |
+----------------------+
```

It created Array of Array

```
 C: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+----------------------+
|         C            |
+----------------------+
|[A, B, C, A, B, C]    |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: try: `df.selectExpr('flatten(array_repeat(COL1,2)) as C')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark 2.4.0 introduced the [`flatten()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten) function which removes one level of array nesting. Given that 2.4.0 is the same version of Spark that introduced `array_repeat()`, you simply need to wrap your call to `array_repeat()` in `flatten()`:

```
>>> df.select(flatten(array_repeat(df.COL1, 2)).alias("C")).show(1, False)
+------------------------+
|C                       |
+------------------------+
|[A, B, C, A, A, B, C, A]|
+------------------------+
```